# How to automatically get user's wallet info if they are connected but NOT show the metamask pop up if they are not?

Tags: web3js, metamask, javascript

I don't want metamask to pop up on page load forcing a user to connect, so we only connect via a button - but after a user is connected if they refresh the page - they need to press the button again to connect (although nothing happens in metamask, it just calls `ethereum.enable()` and closes).

I'd like to be able to do something like:

If user has already connected (after reloading the page or coming back next week), call enable and get their wallet info/address.

If the user has not already connected - do not call the connect function for metamask until the user presses the connect button.

Here is my code for connecting a wallet and I'm unsure how to do the initial check for - "if they have already connected".

```
export const loadUserWeb3 = async () => {
  try {
    if (window.ethereum) {
      window.web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
      await window.ethereum.enable();
      window.ethereum.on("chainChanged", () => {
        document.location.reload();
      });
      return window.web3;
    } else if (window.web3) {
      window.web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);
      return window.web3;
    } else {
      window.web3 = new Web3(
        new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(INFURA_ENDPOINT[1])
      );
      return window.web3;
    }
  } catch {
    window.web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(INFURA_ENDPOINT[1]));
    return window.web3;
  }
};
```

Again the key here is that if they have not already connected then it would not call `enable()` because that would show the metamask pop up without the user asking for it to be shown.

TL;DR:

How to get the user's wallet info if their wallet is ALREADY connected and they just reload the page - without forcing metamask to ask them to connect if they HAVEN'T connected.

Comment: MetaMask might not have this functionality because of privacy reasons. At least all dApps I use always ask to reconnect with MetaMask.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution will depend a little bit on your front-end. This is how I did to cover your requirements with React in TypeScript:

```
    React.useEffect(() => {
       const checkConnection = async () => {

           // Check if browser is running Metamask
           let web3: any;
           if (window.ethereum) {
               web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
           } else if (window.web3) {
               web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);
           };

           // Check if User is already connected by retrieving the accounts
           web3.eth.getAccounts()
               .then(async (addr: string) => {
                   // Set User account into state
               });
       };
       checkConnection();
   }, []);
```

When Users connect to the web page, I check if there is a web3 plugin in browser and try to retrieve the accounts. If I get any result, it means the User is already connected to Metamask and don't need to trigger any pop-up to connect.

If the User is not connected to Metamask, then you can trigger the pop-up by pressing the button you mentioned, and you will execute a similar code but including `await window.ethereum.enable();`

If you are not using React, then you just need to execute this function the first time you load the page and skip the `useEffect` method.

Comment: Thanks. So easy. My problem was I was automatically calling enable without checking accounts first.

Comment: Note that `getAccounts` is deprecated in favour of the eth_accounts [RPC call](https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API#eth_accounts)

Comment: when the user is not logged into metamask, a login window appears...

Answer (score 2):

you can also use ethers js.

```
import { ethers } from "ethers";
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(
  (window as any).ethereum
);
const addresses = await provider.listAccounts(); 
// it doesn't create metamask popup
if (addresses.length) 
// permission already granted so request account address from metamask
else { do other stuff }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had the same problem. I think I came up with a complete solution:

```
//For Metamask detection
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@metamask/detect-provider/dist/detect-provider.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
//wait till page loads up, and than call startApp function
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  startApp();
})

async function startApp() {

 const provider = await detectEthereumProvider()//uses function from "detect-provider.min.js" 

 if (provider) {
  console.log('Metamask successfully detected!');
  
  //RPC call that check if there are address in this wallet
  window.ethereum.sendAsync({
  method: "eth_accounts",
  params: [],
  jsonrpc: "2.0",
  id: new Date().getTime()
  } , function (error, result){
      console.log(result);
      if (result["result"]!="") alert("wallet connected");//addresses found. result["result"] contains wallet address
      else alert("wallet not connected");//found not address, which mean this wallet is not logged in
   });
  
 }
 else {// Metamask is not installed
  alert("Please install Metamask");
 }  
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Modifying Sergi's answer with this code will prevent MetaMask from popping up on pageload if no wallet is found.

```js
const loggedIn = (await web3.eth.getAccounts()).length > 0;

if (loggedIn) {
    web3.eth.getAccounts().then(async (addr) => {
        const accounts = await web3.eth.requestAccounts();
        setAccount(accounts[0])
    });
}
```