# Metamask API: can't detect events "connect" and "disconnect" in React.js

Tags: metamask, events, react

Hello I'm very new to developing.

I'm testing communication with Metamask via React.js

I managed to succesfully listen to Network and Account changes, but when I try to detect if someone "connected" or "disconnected" from my App, I'm not able to receive the event.

Metamask API Documentation I'm using:
https://docs.metamask.io/guide/ethereum-provider.html#connect

**Working:**

- `ethereum.on('accountsChanged', handler: (accounts: Array<string>) => void);`
- `ethereum.on('chainChanged', handler: (chainId: string) => void);`

'

**Not Working:**

- `ethereum.on('connect', handler: (connectInfo: ConnectInfo) => void);`
- `ethereum.on('disconnect', handler: (error: ProviderRpcError) => void);`

**the following Code is working flawless in my React.js app (using React.Component)**

```
  async checkAccountChange() {
   const ethereum = window.ethereum
   if (ethereum) {
     // Listening to Event
     ethereum.on('accountsChanged', accounts => {
       console.log(accounts[0])
       this.setState({ account: accounts[0] })
  })
}
```

}

**the following Code on the other hand is not giving me any console output**

```
  async checkMetamaskHasConnected() {
    if (window.ethereum) {
      window.ethereum.on('connect', () => {
      console.log("Metamask connected")
      this.setState({ metamaskHasConnected: true })
  })
}
```

}

```
  async checkMetamaskHasDisconnected() {
    const ethereum = window.ethereum
      if (ethereum) {
      // Listening to Event
      ethereum.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log("MetaMask discconnected")
        this.setState({ metamaskHasDisonnected: true })
  })
}
```

}

consider that I'm a very fresh beginner and just do learning by doing

Answer (score 3):

If your requirement is:

> detect if someone "connected" or "disconnected" from my App

the methods [connect](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/ethereum-provider.html#connect) and [disconnect](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/ethereum-provider.html#disconnect) you are trying might not help, as they are intended to know if your connection to the blockchain is available or not (for instance, when a user already connected tries to launch a transaction but the RPC connection is down).

Perhaps this [post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/89848/how-to-automatically-get-users-wallet-info-if-they-are-connected-but-not-show-t) can help you. With the combination of `getAccounts()` and `currentProvider` you can deduce if a user is connected or not.

Otherwise, if this is only about knowing if a user is connected or not **to your website**, you may use WebSockets (depending on your architecture).

Answer (score 2):

Hello Sir You Could Wait For Event To Be Fired When Disconnecting(User Deletes Connection in Metamask From Dapp) And Then Dispatch A Action With New Address If there is any other Accounts Currently Connected To Dapp else you Can Call Disconnect Function

```
  const provider = await new web3(web3.givenProvider);
  provider.on('accountsChanged', (code: number, reason: string)=> {
      const accountSwitch = code[0];
                        if (accountSwitch){
                            if (accountSwitch) {
                                dispatch({
                                    type: _const.ADDRESS,
                                    payload: { address: accountSwitch }
                                })
                            }
                        }else{
                            DisconnectFromWallet();
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe This is what you are looking for sir :

```
 window.ethereum.on("accountsChanged", async function(accounts) {
   
  console.log(accounts)
 
  const network = await Ethereum.eth.getChainId()

  if (network !== 1 && network !== 4 ) //must be on mainnet or Testnet
  {
   
    props.onAcountChange(false,false)
  }
  else{

    //Do this check to detect if the user disconnected their wallet from the Dapp
    if( accounts && accounts[0])
      props.onAcountChange(accounts[0], true)
    else{ 

      /*
        @Arg1 : account address (String)
        @Arg2 : isAuthenticated (bool) 
      */
      props.onAcountChange(false,false) 

      /*
        @Arg1 : chain ID (Int)
        @Arg2 : isAuthenticated (bool) 
      */
      props.onNetworkChange(false,false)
    }

  } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use watchers from @wagmi/core to detect connection (same for the network change if needed)

```
    private setupWatchers(): void {
        watchAccount((accountData) => {
            console.log('accountData', accountData);
            if (accountData.isConnected) {
                // do your stuff
            } else {
                // do your stuff
            }
        });

        watchNetwork((networkData) => {
            if (networkData.chain) {
                // do your stuff
            }
        });
    }
```